# Executing a Function Between Script Files

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Tell me please. I have 2 scripts that hang on different Unity objects. The first script is for clicking a button. The second one is for executing the function.
How can I execute the AddItem function if the button is pressed?

Script 1 (button click):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class UseButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerDownHandler
{
    public bool isClick = false;
 
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData ped) 
    {
        isClick = true;

    }
    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData ped) 
    {

        isClick = false;
    }
}
```

Script 2 (Adding Items):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class InventoryManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void AddItem(ItemScriptableObject _item, int _amount)
    {

        

        foreach(InventorySlot slot in slots)
        {
            if (slot.item == _item)
            {
                slot.amount += _amount;
                return;
            }
        }
        foreach(InventorySlot slot in slots)
        {
            //print(_item+" "+_amount);
            if (slot.isEmpty == true)
            {
                slot.item = _item;
                slot.amount = _amount;
                slot.isEmpty = false;
                slot.SetIcon(_item.icon);
                return; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wel arguably one of the better ways is to make your isclick a property and have an event that things can subscribe to. Then you can safely do whatever you liked onclick.

Comment: @BugFinder Can you show an example how to do it?

Comment: I am not trying to type out a full example on a phone. Google propertys and events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont have a variable on the second script, of the first script, you should do that by using:

```
GameObject go;
go.GetComponent<InventoryManager>();
```

try changing the first script to something like:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class UseButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerDownHandler
{
    public bool isClick = false;
    
    void Update() 
    {
         if (isClick)
         {
              Debug.Log("do something")
         }
    }
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData ped) 
    {
        isClick = true;

    }
    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData ped) 
    {

        isClick = false;
    }
}
```

This way you can modify the variable: is Click easily.